# How to write C program that accepts user input that contain both integers and punctuation characters?

Tags: c, linux, assembly

*Solution*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 int main()
{
    char value[50];
    char *end;
    int sum = 0;
    long conv;
    while(conv != 0 )
    {
            printf("Enter a measurement and unit(Ex: 4' or 3\";0' or 0\" when done): ");
            fgets(value, 50, stdin);
            conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
            if(strstr(value, "\'") != NULL)
            {
                    conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
                    sum = sum + (conv*12);
            }
            else if(strstr(value, "\"") != NULL)
            {
                    conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
                    sum = sum + conv;
            }
    }
    printf("Total: %d, %s\n", sum, "inches" );
    return 0;
}
```

*UPDATE* Still having problems with new program..unsure where to go from here. It is accepting numbers and quotes, but it keeps multiplying any number I type in by 12 when it should only do that if I enter a single quote to specify feet.
*UPDATE2* Here are the functions for Assembly that we should keep in mind for writing the C program:

```
void printStr(char *)
 Arguments:
 edi = address of null-terminated string to print
 Returns:
    Nothing

void printUInt(unsigned)
 Arguments:
 edi = Unsigned integer to print
 Returns:
  Nothing

 char getchar()
  Arguments:
  None
  Returns:
   eax = the next character

 uinsigned readUInt()
 Arguments:
 None
 Returns:
  eax = an unsigned int read from stdin.
       (eax is 0 on error)
```

I must write a C program which prompts the user to enter a measurement(number) and unit( ' or ", which represent feet or inches) and then prints out the Total length in inches AFTER the user enters a length of '0' which acts as a sentinel value.

This program is only needed to act as a way for me to then build an Assembly program with a similar structure. The thing is, it must be built around 4 functions that would be called to help perform some of the operations.

So my C program should be built similarly with those functions in mind. Here's what I have:

Here is my program:

UPDATED:

```
int main()
{
    char value[50];
    char *end;
    int sum = 0;
    long conv;
    while(conv != 0)
    {
            printf("Enter a measurement and unit: ");
            fgets(value, 50, stdin);
            conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
            if(value[1]='\'')
            {
                    sum = sum + (conv*12);
            }
            if(value[1]='\"')
            {
                    sum = sum + conv;
            }
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

OLD:

```
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int value;
    char symbol;

    while(value != 1)
    {
            printf("Enter measurement and unit: ");
            scanf("%d,%d", &value, &symbol);

            if(symbol == "'")
            {
                    sum = sum + value*12;
            }
            else if(symbol == ''' )
            {
                    sum = sum + value;
            }

            sum = sum + value;
    }
    printf("Total: %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope I have enough information here for someone to help me even though I know we're missing the complete functions for time being. And I know the IA32 assembly conversion is not my main question and I think I will save that for another if I get stuck, but I hope getting this High-Level language program corrected will get me going in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `scanf` is not useful for this kind of thing unless you use obscure conversion specifiers that essentially just turn it into `fgets`. You need to be using `fgets` to get a whole line then parsing it yourself.

Comment: What about gets() ? I do not like that fgets requires a size for the string. I then would need to translate part of the string to an integer too.

Comment: No. Whoever you learned `gets` from is someone you should never again consult for learning C. The function is impossible to use safely and is not even part of the current language -- it was actually removed because it's unusable.

Comment: Translating the decimal string to an integer is pretty easy to do yourself or you can use `strtol` or `sscanf`.

Comment: Thanks. Now what about parsing the ' or " ? It will also be entered alongside the number by the user.

Comment: Given you are going to dump to assembly, you probably want to stick with `read` to read the input, and`write` to write the output as they have direct correlation to assembly system calls. The character equality can be a simple comparison, and the sum can be simple addition.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am not familiar with read and write in C, and I cannot find any good examples of how to use it!

Comment: I'll put an example together for you, but it will be in the morning after a few hours of sleep. They are just the basic low-level I/O functions. Take a look and `man 2 read` and `man 2 write`. The example will show their use.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I am not sure I have enough time to rewrite another program with new stuff I'm not familiar with. I just need to get this C program working really soon and I feel like I'm close.

Comment: Jay, I added changes to **your** code at the bottom of my answer. Note, it will expect entry of `number"` for inches and `number'` for feet. (e.g.: `10'` for 10 feet) **Double Note**: when you dump your code to assembly, it ain't going to be pretty `:p`

Answer (score 1):

Get the character using `%c` not `%d`. Change the line into like this.

```
if ( scanf("%d,%c", &value, &symbol) != 2 )
       continue;
```

While comparing you have to do like this,

```
if(symbol == '\"')
{
           sum = sum + value*12;
}
else if(symbol == '\'' )
{
              sum = sum + value;
}
```

Output after this,

```
Enter measurement and unit: 2,"
Enter measurement and unit: 3,'
Enter measurement and unit: 1,"
Total: 45
```

Comment: Also, *always* test the result (scanned item count) of `scanf`

Comment: Thanks for the catch. But I cannot have the comma in between the number and the quotation mark.

Comment: Thanks, now how I can I get it to work so 'while(value != 0)' instead of 'while(value != 1)' , also, how can it work without having to add a comma for user input?

Comment: For removing the comma from the user input, just remove the `,` in the `scanf` function.

Answer (score 1):

When you think about writing a program that will be translated to assembly, you want to limit yourself to using calls that have a 1-to-1 correlation to the system calls available in assembly. That means leaving the high-level world of buffered input/output and using the unbuffered low-level input/output methods where you are responsible for counting each byte that goes in or out of the program. Even the low-level routines of `read` and `write` in C, provide quite a few features that you will have to handle by hand in assembly.

In order to provide a reasonable example of this low-level I/O, I've written a short example to take your input measurements in either feet or inches and keep a running total of the feet and inches entered. The code also converts any inches over 12 into feet accordingly. This example provides a good approximation of the approach you will take in assembly to do the same thing. Take time to understand what each part does, and let me know if you have questions. The lower-level code you write, the longer it becomes to accomplish seemingly simple tasks. Your assembly will probably be 3-times longer.

The program expects input of the form `numfeet'` or `numinches"`. So to enter 10 feet, enter `10'`, for 10 inches, enter `10"`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STDINFD 0
#define STDOUTFD 1
#define newline write (STDOUTFD, "\n", 1)

#define MAXS 32

int main (void) {

    ssize_t n = 0;              /* number of characters read    */
    size_t i = 0;               /* general iteration variable   */
    size_t digits = 0;          /* digit counter                */
    char buf[MAXS] = {0};       /* buffer to hold input         */
    char *bp = buf;             /* pointer to input buffer      */
    char length[MAXS] = {0};    /* buffer to hold measurement   */
    char *p = length;           /* pointer to measurement       */
    char fbuf[MAXS] = {0};      /* buffer to hold feet          */
    char *fp = fbuf;            /* pointer to feet              */
    char ibuf[MAXS] = {0};      /* buffer to hold inches        */
    char *ip = ibuf;            /* pointer to inches            */
    unsigned feet = 0;          /* total feet entered           */
    unsigned inches = 0;        /* total inches entered         */
    unsigned num = 0;           /* general unsigned value       */
    unsigned mlt = 1;           /* place multiplier value       */
    unsigned incvt = 0;         /* inches to feet conversion    */
    char unit = 0;              /* buffer for ''' or '"'        */
    char const digit[] = "0123456789";  /* conversion string    */

    /* input prompt and labels */
    char prompt[] = "\n Enter measurement with units [feet' or inches\"]: ";
    char nlabel[] = "\n number : ";
    char ulabel[] = "\n   unit : ";
    char flabel[] = "\n   feet : ";
    char ilabel[] = "\n inches : ";

    /* write prompt to stdout */
    write (STDOUTFD, prompt, sizeof prompt);

    /* read length and unit until [CTRL+D] entered */
    while ((n = read (STDINFD, bp, 32)) != 0)
    {
        /* re-initialize values for each loop */
        bp = buf;
        p = length;
        fp = fbuf;
        ip = ibuf;
        i = 0;
        num = 0;
        incvt = 0;
        mlt = 1;
        unit = 0;

        /* parse each character read into buf */
        while (bp[i] != '\n')
        {

            if (bp[i] >= '0' && bp[i] <= '9')   /* is a digit   */
                *p++ = bp[i];

            if (bp[i] == 0x27)                  /* is a '       */
                unit = bp[i];

            if (bp[i] == '"')                   /* is a "       */
                unit = bp[i];

            i++;
        }

        /* null-terminate / decrement length pointer */
        *p = 0;
        p--;

        /* write length and unit to stdout */
        write (STDOUTFD, nlabel, sizeof nlabel);
        write (STDOUTFD, length, p - length + 1);
        write (STDOUTFD, ulabel, sizeof ulabel);
        write (STDOUTFD, &unit, sizeof unit);
        newline;

        /* convert characters in length to number */
        for (i = p - length; p >= length; p--)
        {
            num += (*p - '0') * mlt;
            mlt *= 10;
        }

        /* test unit and add to feet or inches */
        if (unit == '"')
            inches += num;
        if (unit == 0x27)
            feet += num;

        /* convert inches > 12 to feet */
        if (inches > 12)
        {
            incvt = inches / 12;
            inches -= incvt * 12;
            feet += incvt;
        }

        /* write label for total feet to stdout */
        write (STDOUTFD, flabel, sizeof flabel);

            /* determine number of digits in feet */
            i = 1;
            digits = 0;
            while (feet >= i && (1UL << 32))
            {
                digits++;
                i *= 10;
            }

            /* convert number to characters in feet buffer */
            num = feet;
            fp += digits - 1;
            while (fp >= fbuf)
            {
                *fp-- =  digit [num % 10];
                num /= 10;
            }

        /* write the number of feet and label for inches to stdout */
        write (STDOUTFD, fbuf, digits);
        write (STDOUTFD, ilabel, sizeof flabel);

            /* determine number of digits in inches */
            i = 1;
            digits = 0;
            while (inches >= i && (1UL << 32))
            {
                digits++;
                i *= 10;
            }

            /* convert number to characters in inches buffer */
            num = inches;
            ip += digits - 1;
            while (ip >= ibuf)
            {
                *ip-- =  digit [num % 10];
                num /= 10;
            }

        /* write the number of inches and newline to stdout */
        write (STDOUTFD, ibuf, digits);
        newline;

        /* zero all buffers */
        for (i = 0; i < MAXS; i++)
            buf[i] = length[i] = fbuf[i] = ibuf[i] = 0;

        /* prompt for next input ([CTRL+D] to quit) */
        write (STDOUTFD, prompt, sizeof prompt);

    }

    newline;

    return 0;
}
```

**Example / Output**

```
$ ./bin/read_measurement

 Enter measurement with units [feet' or inches"]: 10"

 number : 10
   unit : "

   feet :
 inches : 10

 Enter measurement with units [feet' or inches"]: 10'

 number : 10
   unit : '

   feet : 10
 inches : 10

 Enter measurement with units [feet' or inches"]: 4"

 number : 4
   unit : "

   feet : 11
 inches : 2

 Enter measurement with units [feet' or inches"]:
```

---

**Update to your high-level code**

If you are going to continue to use the high-level functions, then make use of the fact that `end` already points to the next character following the number after you call `strtol`. e.g.:

```
while (printf ("\nEnter a measurement and unit: ") && fgets (value, 50 - 1, stdin))
{

    errno = 0;
    conv = strtol (value, &end, 10);

    if (errno == 0 && value != end)
    {
        if (*end == '\'')
            sum = sum + (conv*12);
        else if (*end == '\"')
            sum = sum + conv;
        else
            printf ("error: no unit following number.\n");
    }
    else
        printf ("error: no value read.\n");
}
```

Comment: There's no reason why a program hand-written in assembly as an exercise cannot or should not take advantage of C library functionality when useful.  If the compiler can generate machine code to call it, so can you.

Comment: Conversely, if you are for-serious programming on the bare metal, except for the small handful of constructs that *can't* be expressed in C (e.g. the guts of a context switch) and the somewhat larger set of computational primitives that can still benefit from hand tuning, there is no reason to write in assembly language.  C has its "freestanding environment" for just this purpose.

Comment: You are correct, but from a practical standpoint, the huge leap in understanding required to dump code full of library functions to assembly and understand what you are looking at from a beginners standpoint, might as well be Greek. Reserving space for your buffers, and utilizing the equivalent `syscall` calls can greatly reduce the size of the leap.

Answer (score 1):

I see several bugs in your "updated" code: one on nearly every line.

```
int main()
```

Header files missing.  (It's much easier for us to help you if you give us a *complete* program that can be compiled and tested without modification.)

Should be `int main(void)`; empty argument parentheses are poor style.

```
{
    char value[50];
    char *end;
    int sum = 0;
```

This is fine.

```
    long conv;
    while(conv != 0)
```

Use of uninitialized variable.  I would write a do-while loop instead.

```
    {
            printf("Enter a measurement and unit: ");
```

Unnecessary use of `printf` (better `fputs` since no formatting is required).

```
            fgets(value, 50, stdin);
```

If you have `getline`, use it.

```
            conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
```

It is necessary to set `errno` to zero manually before any use of the `strto*` functions, because some errors are only visible that way.

```
            if(value[1]='\'')
```

***Your immediate problem is here.***  There are three bugs on this line:

- You haven't checked whether `strtol` returned an error.
- `value[1]` is the *second character read by `fgets`*, not the character immediately after the number.  The character immediately after the number is `end[0]`.
- Comparison uses `==`, not `=`; this condition is *assigning* `'\''` to `value[1]` and then testing whether `'\''` is nonzero; since `'\''` has to be nonzero, the body of the if-statement always executes, which is why you are seeing it always multiply by 12.  This would have been more obvious if you had put spaces around the `=`.  If you had run the compiler with warnings enabled, it would have told you about this mistake.

```
            {
                    sum = sum + (conv*12);
            }
```

ok

```
            if(value[1]='\"')
```

Same problems as the earlier `if`-statement; should be `else if`.

```
            {
                    sum = sum + conv;
            }
```

Missing `else` clause here in which you report an error because the character after the number was neither `'` nor `"`.

Missing check for junk input after the number and unit specifier.

```
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

the rest is fine

---

You probably could also use a primer on how to check whether `strtol` returned an error.  This is a little finicky, because `strtol` has no special return value that indicates an error; if an error happened, it will either set `errno`, or *not consume any characters*.  Unfortunately, when an error did *not* happen, it does not necessarily clear `errno`, so you have to do it yourself:

```
errno = 0;
conv = strtol(value, &end, 0);
if (end == value || errno) {
    fputs("Invalid number, or no number entered\n", stderr);
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I came up with a solution a little earlier but never did add 'errno' for error checking. That said, look up at my solution and see what you think.

Comment: @Jay Well, it depends on how picky you want this parser to be.  The `strstr` technique will accept any amount of junk on the line after the number as long as it happens to have a ' or " in it.

Comment: that's fine with me, as long as it doesn't mess up the addition, which from my testing, it doesn't! Appreciate the help!