# C program read in values in to two separate parts?

Tags: c, assembly

-NOT a duplicate. Program goal is same, but need a different way of doing it, which is explained below. The problem has TWO parts and if I don't do the first part exactly how it needs to be, then I can't do the second.-

I need to write a C program, and then write an Assembly program that works functionally the same based off that C program. I found that my C program: which reads in user input that contains a number and then a single (') or double (") to represent feet and inches and keeps prompting user until they enter 0, then sums up all their entries and prints the total length in inches, will not work with the following Assembly functions:

```
void printStr(char *)
 Arguments:
 edi = address of null-terminated string to print
 Returns:
 Nothing

void printUInt(unsigned)
Arguments:
 edi = Unsigned integer to print
Returns:
 Nothing

char getchar()
Arguments:
 None
Returns:
 eax = the next character

uinsigned readUInt()
Arguments:
 None
Returns:
 eax = an unsigned int read from stdin.
       (eax is 0 on error)
```

here is the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char value[50];
    char *end;
    int sum = 0;
    int conv;
    do
    {
            printf("Enter a measurement and unit(Ex: 4' or 3\"; 0' or 0\"    when done): ");
            fgets(value, 50, stdin);
            conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
            if(strstr(value, "\'") != NULL)
            {
                    conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
                    sum = sum + (conv*12);
            }
            else if(strstr(value, "\"") != NULL)
            {
                    conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
                    sum = sum + conv;
            }
    }
    while (conv != 0);

    printf("Total: %d, %s\n", sum, "inches" );
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently I cannot "parse the number and quotation marks into parts". I need to use functions that work similar to the Assembly functions listed above. I'm not sure what to use because I feel like I've already tried some similar to them. I was told strtol() is similar to readUInt(), I guess that's good? Anyway, instead of parsing a string in to parts from stdin, I need to "read in the values in the values in to two separate parts". So I guess the difference is instead of reading in one part and then parsing, I need to read the input as two different values right off the bat. How can I do this with what I currently have? Please take note of what the Assembly functions can do. I must be able to use those functions in place of the C functions when I go to writing the Assembly version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write C program that accepts user input that contain both integers and punctuation characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443359/how-to-write-c-program-that-accepts-user-input-that-contain-both-integers-and-pu)

Comment: I got the correct answer for that question. It just turned out that the solution has issues which I detail in this question. I need a new solution.

Comment: I guess you need to be more specific about how what you need here is different from the last question. They look very nearly identical. Perhaps drill down to exactly what the issue is. I'll take another look at the question. I think the problem is confusion. You have not listed any assembly functions. `printStr` `printUnit` `getStr` and `getUnit` are NOT assembly functions. Assembly has no "quote/unquote" functions. It has "directives" or "operators". They do very rudimentary things. You can put them together into functions, but the are not functions themselves.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is **I need help writing these functions**, right?

Comment: No, those functions are already written and stored in an encrypted .o file. I can call those functions when writing Assembly according to the assignment. I can't view what the functions contain other than what's given to me which I show in this question.

Comment: I don't need help writing ANY functions. I need to use built-in C functions that are similar to those functions listed above. I cannot parse the string entered by the user and then convert it to an integer using strtol()(which is what is currently happening in my C program). It needs to be read in to two separate parts(number and quotation mark) right as it's entered by user. The functions I use just need to function the same as the functions I will use in the Assembly program.

Comment: Oh, that is tricky. So the prof gives you an object file with functions already compiled and tells you to write a program to use them...  The big hangup here, and in your last question, is there doesn't seem to be anything related to **Assembly** language. Your prof has created C functions that do basic operations and you are supposed to use them in your code to accomplish the goal. That makes it almost **impossible** for anyone here to offer meaningful help because we can't see what is in `encrypted.o`. We'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yea it's VERY tricky and I'm not sure what to do since I cannot see those functions either.

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirements that you use only the functions provided in `encrypted.o`, there are some assumptions you must make. (1) `encrypted.o` contains the function definitions. (2) it has a header file you can include so you can make use of the functions provided. (3) `readUInt` will stop reading after is reaches the first non-digit character and put it back in `stdin`.

With those criteria, and using only the functions provided, your code would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* encrypted.h must contain declarations for the functions below, and
   must contain all required headers beyond `stdio.h` required here */
#include "encrypted.h"

/* function prototypes */
void printStr(char *);
void printUInt(unsigned);
unsigned readUInt();

int main(void)
{
    int c = 0;                 /* always initialize ALL variables */
    unsigned measurement = 0;
    unsigned sum = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printStr ("Enter a measurement and unit(Ex: 4' or 3\"; 0' or 0\"    when done): ");

        /* read/validate measurement with readUInt() */
        if ((measurement = readUInt()) == 0|| measurement == EOF) {
            printStr ("notice: 0 read as measurement, or [CTRL+D] pressed, exiting.\n");
            break;
        }

        /* read/validate unit with getchar() */
        if (!(c = getchar()) || c == EOF) {
            printStr ("error: 0 unable to read unit.\n");

            /* empty the input buffer */
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

            /* get next input */
            continue;
        }

        if ( c == '\'')
        {
            sum += measurement * 12;        /* update sum as inches */
        }
        else if (c == '\"')
        {
            sum += measurement;             /* update sum as feet   */
        }
        else
            printStr ("error: invalid or no unit read.\n");

        /* empty the input buffer */
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }

    /* print final result using only printStr & printUInt */

    printStr ("\nTotal: ");
    printUInt (sum);
    printStr (" inches.\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Note** without `encrypted.o/encrypted.h` there is no way for anyone but you to test. Compile with something similar to:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -c -o yourfile.o yourfile.c
```

Link with something similar to:

```
ld -o yourprog yourfile.o encrypted.o
```

If you can provide `encrypted.o` we can test.

Comment: … and let the compiler do the assembly-writing for you with `gcc -S -O …`

Comment: the name of the object file is asmIO.o , I included it in my program but it's not compiling. Keeps telling me "addO.c:6:20: error: asmIO.o: No such file or directory" but I know it's in there. How do I provide you with the object file?

Comment: `No such file or directory` where is it located ? Did you add it to the `gcc` command line ?  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -c -o progname addO.c yourfile.c`  Post it to `pastebin.com`

Comment: This honestly doesn't seem like the right solution. You are actually using the functions from the object file when in my question above, I state: "I need to use functions that work *similar* to the Assembly functions listed above." The C program just needs to be comparable to the Assembly program I write, not the actual program. And your way of compiling the program is confusing to me. I'll try to provide the object file but this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: The only thing that makes sense, since you have no source code for the functions, is that your prof has precompiled the functions in the object file he has given you. (which is common) That is why he/you state "using only the four assembly functions" provided. Otherwise the entire scenario makes no sense. The alternative is to ignore the four functions, write whatever you want, and ignore the fact he has given you an object file.... Just what do you think is in `asmIO.o`? (you can check with `objdump`...)

Comment: I think I will just write whatever I want and go from there. I'm running out of time and need to just turn something in. I'm guessing what is in the asmIO.o file is the functions.

Comment: Alright. Good luck. If you get a chance, run `objdump` on `asmIO.o` just to see if it contains the functions. Regardless, if you get stuck, drop another comment on where you are stuck along with the error and I'm happy to help.

Comment: I found there is a function called getChar() in stdio.h so I used that instead. It's working perfectly now.

Comment: Yes, and if you look closely, you will find the only header file included in my answer is `stdio.h` -- specifically for `getchar()`, which is the same `getchar()` your prof wants you to use. The only non-libc functions your prof has you using are `printStr`, `printUInt`, and `readUInt`. That is what I understood from your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int value;
    int unit;
    int sum =0;
    do
    {
            printf("Enter a measurement and unit(Ex: 4' or 3\"; 0' or 0\" when done): ");
            scanf("%d,%d", &value, &unit);
            unit = getchar();
            if(unit == '\'')
            {
                    sum = sum + (value*12);
            }
            else if(unit == '\"')
            {
                    sum = sum + value;
            }
    }
    while (value != 0);

    printf("Total: %d, %s\n", sum, "inches" );
    return 0;
}
```